# DO I need to setup sql server in a computer to run c# desktop application file made in vs 10?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a desktop application made in vs 10 with sql server 8. I have added the mdf file in app_code folder of project and the app.config is changed accordingly.The application is published and is availabel as setup file(.exe).If i want to install it in another pc, do i need to install the sql server in that pc?

Comment: vs 10?  sql server 8?  Do you mean VS 2010 and Sql Server 2008?  As to your question, is the database the program using on another machine, or does it need to be included in the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is Yes

The idea is database needs a server to host it and an engine to run it

mdf file has no value without sql serve and access files has nothing to do if you don't have MS Access installed, etc.

But this does not mean db server must be installed on the client machine that has the application. as it can be on another machine or on the cloud (i.e. hosted on the internet)

As long as your application is connecting to that machine/server

Comment: So if I need to run the programm offline, it is must to have Sql server.

Comment: yes, exactly .. but if you need to run a small application for personal usage on your laptop or something, I suggest to use light weight db, like sql server express edition or access

Comment: So how do the software that needs database work in our pc when we install them without having to install any other additional software.

Comment: it depends on the program design. some applications store data in its own files, and some applications enforce you to connect to the internet to get their online data. but it the app uses sqlserver as backend, the installer should either ask you to install it or install it on your behalf